# How do I calculate all the relationship properties with py2neo or cypher query language

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

The model is for recording all the browse history

How could I `summation/average/find_max/find_min` for all the pages browse to page 2

The expected answers are

- summation all the browsed time to `page2` : 100+200+300+500
- find_max browse time to `page2` : 500
- find_min browse time to `page2` : 100
- average browse time from `page1` to `page2` : 100

Could Anyone give me some queries to achieve the above questions.

The cypher query syntax is really pianful for me.

[image]

## The code for creating nodes and relationhsips

```
page1 = Node("Page", name="page1")
page2 = Node("Page", name="page2")
page3 = Node("Page", name="page3")
graph_db.create(neo4j.Path(page1, ("LINKS_TO", {"browsed_time": 200}), page2))
graph_db.create(neo4j.Path(page1, ("LINKS_TO", {"browsed_time": 100}), page2))
graph_db.create(neo4j.Path(page1, ("LINKS_TO", {"browsed_time": 300}), page2))
graph_db.create(neo4j.Path(page3, ("LINKS_TO", {"browsed_time": 500}), page2))
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Try to solve the problem on your own and if you experience any difficulties, post it on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example, you'll need to adapt to match exactly your needs, test console here : http://console.neo4j.org/?id=rs4ado

**Example 1:** Summing all the relationships properties keyed "time" :

```
MATCH (p:Page { id:2 })<-[r:LINKS_TO]-(referer)
RETURN sum(r.time) AS totalTime
```

For average, replace `sum` by `avg`, same for `min` and `max`.

**Example 2:** If you need to get the page node that is linked to Page2, here get the one with the most time, so sort relationship time property in descending order

```
MATCH (p:Page { id:2 })
MATCH (p)<-[r:LINKS_TO]-(referer)
WITH r
ORDER BY r.time DESC 
LIMIT 1
RETURN startNode(r), r.time
```